# Pass binary resource to JNI layer

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, resources

I need to load a raw binary resource in an Android app and pass it to a JNI function. To avoid copying data, I have to use allocateDirect() and GetDirectBufferAddress():

On the Java side:

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(size);
```

On the JNI side:

```
const uint8_t* buf = (const uint8_t*)env->GetDirectBufferAddress(i_buf);
```

At the same time, in order to read the resource into the byte buffer, I need to use the ByteBuffer.wrap() method:

```
data = new byte[istream.available()];
istream.read(data);
buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
```

These two approaches seem incompatible. The byte buffer can be either wrapped, or direct, but not both. This results in the necessity to create at least one copy of the whole resource, either when loading it into the direct byte buffer (by using an intermediate wrapped buffer), or when accessing data from a non-direct buffer in the JNI layer.

Is there any way to avoid this extra copying of data when passing a binary resource to the JNI layer?

Comment: yes, you can use piped streams (out and in) but it would require two threads (one for a producer and cone for a consumer)

Comment: but actually why not to use https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/asset?

Comment: I cannot find reliable info on the maximum size of an asset file for different Android versions. Some time ago this was 1MB, which is below the size I need.

Comment: ok but your "binary resource" is a file, right? if so, why not read it directly?

Comment: it is not technically a file, it is part of the res/raw compressed folder inside the apk file.

Comment: so see my first comment above - use a pipe

Comment: i need random access to bytes in the buffer from JNI code.

Comment: sorry you cannot have random access - you would need to reset the stream to the beginning and skip some bytes